# Yosemite update crashed and now won't finish

Tags: macos, crash, osx-yosemite

I was updating a MacBook Pro to Yosemite, and it crashed. When the user logs in, it gets stuck here:

[image]

I tried starting in recovery mode, with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and using DiskUtil, I run the repair procedures for permissions and the other one. It still got stuck. I got into recovery mode again and re-installed OS X Yosemite, but it's still getting stuck there.

What can I do now?

Comment: Can't you restore to the backup you took before the upgrade (if any)?

Comment: @slhck, yes, I could, but this was setting up a brand new hard drive from said backup. I'd need to restart the whole process from scratch and the owner of the MacBook is already very annoyed that Migration Assistant doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do it is not likely that it will work. The only way to have Yosemity work normally with Macbooks that do not have SSD drives is to go to Apple and give it to them. They will get you an SSD, install Yosemity and try to persuade you that it's amazing. I spent about a month trying so many things to fix problems caused by Yosemity.

However, if your Mac was bought in mid-2011 or later(it has came with Lion or a newer OS) you can use Internet Recovery and install the OS your Mac came with originally. To boot into Internet Recovery you need to hold down Command+Option+R immediately after you hear the boot chime and before you see the Apple logo. You will then see a spinning globe and will log in the Internet recovery mode where you will be able to install the OS you Mac originally came with.

Comment: This laptop came with an SSD and now has a bigger one that I just put in and with command-r I can trigger the re-installation of Mountain Lion. I'm looking for alternatives to doing that *again*.